# Mongo query for date range in ISODate format

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to create this query to use with jasper reports but something is wrong with my syntax, i have 2 `ISODates` in my db and i want to query between then, in this query I use `$match` and `$gt`, `$lt`.

Anyway something is not correct because the console says error but doesn`t specify it.

Obs: The problem is something with the `$match` and the `$lt` and `$gt.` because without them it is possible to query.

Code:

```
{
    runCommand : { 
        aggregate : 'saleCalculation', 
        pipeline : [
            { 
                $match: {
                    processingInfo.modifiedDate: {$gt : ISODate("2016-05-01T09:29:40.572Z")}, 
                    {$lt : ISODate("2016-06-01T09:29:40.572Z")} 
                } 
            },        
            { 
                $project : { 
                    header.documentCode : 1, 
                    header.transactionDate : 1, 
                    header.metadata.entityName : 1, 
                    lines : 1 
                }
            },
            { $unwind  : '$lines'},
            { $unwind  :'$lines.calculatedTax.details' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Jasper Manual says i need to do something like that:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-query-mongo-isodate-data-parameter

but i didn't understand that

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
{
    runCommand : { 
        aggregate : 'saleCalculation', 
        pipeline : [
            { 
                $match: {
                    processingInfo.modifiedDate: {$gt : ISODate("2016-05-01T09:29:40.572Z"), 
                    $lt : ISODate("2016-06-01T09:29:40.572Z")} 
                } 
            },        
            { 
                $project : { 
                    header.documentCode : 1, 
                    header.transactionDate : 1, 
                    header.metadata.entityName : 1, 
                    lines : 1 
                }
            },
            { $unwind  : '$lines'},
            { $unwind  :'$lines.calculatedTax.details' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pipeline. Make sure to use double quotes.

```
    [
        { "$match": {"processingInfo.modifiedDate": { "$gt":ISODate("2010-03-26T18:40:59.000Z"), "$lt":ISODate("2016-09-28T18:40:59.000Z")}}},
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "header.documentCode": 1, 
                "header.transactionDate": 1, 
                "header.metadata.entityName": 1, 
                "lines" : 1 
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$lines"},
        { "$unwind": "$lines.calculatedTax.details" }
    ]
```

I tried this command on mongo shell and it worked without any error.

```
db.runCommand({"aggregate": "saleCalculation", "pipeline" : [
        { "$match": {"processingInfo.modifiedDate": { "$gt":ISODate("2010-03-26T18:40:59.000Z"), "$lt":ISODate("2016-09-28T18:40:59.000Z")}}},
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "header.documentCode": 1, 
                "header.transactionDate": 1, 
                "header.metadata.entityName": 1, 
                "lines" : 1 
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$lines"},
        { "$unwind": "$lines.calculatedTax.details" }
    ]
})
```